# A turning gear appears when I run this workflow, why?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am running the following script (called `Restart AppleTV`) using automator :

```
on run {input, parameters}

  do shell script "sudo killall coreaudiod" with administrator privileges

  return input
end run
```

However, I get the following in the statusbar :

[image]

The terminal code DOES run, but the gear never disappears unless I manually click the `x` button .. How can I get rid of this automatically or prevent it from appearing in the first place ?

--Note : This only happens when I run it by double clicking the exported .app file, but not when I run the code through automator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set myPassword to "My Password"

    ignoring application responses
        do shell script "sudo killall coreaudiod" password myPassword with administrator privileges
    end ignoring
end run
```

OR

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set myPassword to "My Password"

    ignoring application responses
        do shell script "sudo killall coreaudiod &>/dev/null &" password myPassword with administrator privileges
    end ignoring
end run
```

Comment: The edit fixed it. Can you please explain what you have done ? For personal learning purposes. I see that you added `&>/dev/null &`, what does that do ?

Comment: &>/dev/null & redirects both stdout and stderr so the command is not waiting for a response.

Answer (score 1):

adayzdone's suggestion to route output to dev/null also fixed the spinning gear that was appearing when I used Automator to run Firefox profiles.

So, something like this in a shell script:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P 'Web Dev' -no-remote &>/dev/null &
```

Thanks!